# libvlc - keep window opened between videos

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, vlc, libvlc

I am using python wrapper around libvlc for playing videos. The problem is that after I stop previous video playback and start to play new one, window is reopened. I am trying to achieve state where window is still opened and I can change videos in this window without flash of the desktop behind it.

```
import time
import vlc


i = vlc.Instance()

media_player = i.media_player_new()
media_player.set_fullscreen(True)

m1 = i.media_new('vid1.mp4')
m2 = i.media_new('vid2.mp4')

media_player.set_media(m1)
media_player.play()
time.sleep(5)
media_player.stop()


media_player.set_media(m2)
media_player.play()
time.sleep(5)
media_player.stop()
```

I also tried using `set_xwindow()` function but without success.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Given that you are not envoking a graphical environment, as @mfkl points out, you have no `window` to assign to `vlc`. It therefore creates its own, each time.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481303/set-vlc-window-dimensions-in-vlc-py/56497928#56497928

Comment: @RolfofSaxony This is what I was looking for! Thank you! If you want, I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

libvlc will create (and I guess close) windows if you don't specify one.

You should tell libvlc which window to use. How you do it depends on which platform you use.

- On Linux, use `libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow` with the window handle.
- On Windows `libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd`.
- On macOS, that's `libvlc_media_player_set_nsobject`.

This will allow you to use any given window for successive playbacks.

Comment: I tried to use `media_player.set_xwindow(0)` but it doesn't help. There is still small flash between video playbacks.

Comment: please share your full code and a video of the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think this is solved the problem

```py
hwnd = player.get_hwnd()
player.set_hwnd(hwnd)
```