# Can libvlc display multiple videos at the same time in the same window?

Tags: c++, c, vlc, libvlc

When libvlc starts to display video, it launch new window, can I do otherwise and display multiple videos in the same window?

Comment: Use a "master" app window that contains the player windows as child windows

Comment: I use qml for gui, but there is no way to create child windows inside of parent

Comment: @Egerin re your comment, "you're going to need a bigger boat" - brought to you  courtesy of the film "Jaws". :)

Answer (score 0):

> When libvlc starts to display video, it launch new window

That is the default behavior when you have not told libvlc in which window to draw the video. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65060714/4064749

libvlc currently cannot draw multiple videos in a single window handle. However, you could arrange several windows together and have multiple mediaplayers draw to each of them, creating the illusion that multiple videos are played in the same window.

Comment: I`ve understood you. Thank you for comment!